# How to get consistent results running the same constrained optimization problem multiple times - in scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have written a constrained optimization function using scipy.optimize.minimize. However, when I run the exact same optimization problem multiple times I get variable results. 
I know that it is possible when generating a (pseudo) random number, for example, to provide a seed so that the same numbers are generated on every simulation.

Is there a similar provision for running a constrained optimization problem in scipy?
or to put it another way, is there any random component to the scipy.optimize.minimize function.

I am using the SLSQP method and I am running the optimization with the same starting point.

Comment: I don't think SLSQP is a randomized algorithm. You probably should create a reproducible example for us to look at.

Comment: Can you share your code with us?